# Weights in TableLayout

Tags: libgdx, tablelayout, scene2d

Is there something like weighting possible in [TableLayout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout) .

I want to my three rows of my table to be of same height and expanfd the whole height of table.
I wish to give the three weights of .33f . Is there something like this possible in TableLayout . Android Linearlayout has such a provision.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution

If multiple rows or columns request extpandX/expandY , then the extra space is distributed evenly .

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout#expand